# generate a yaml file dynamically in golang

Tags: go, reflection, yaml

I want to generate a yaml file using a struct's yaml tags, but I want to ignore the omitempty tags. So I figured I should go over the struct recursively with reflection, and get the information using Tag.GetTag("yaml"). 
This is fine, but it leaves me with the task of creating a yaml with this information. 
I started writing this -

```
const Indent = "  "
const NL = ":\n"

type Yaml struct {
    Simple []string
    Slices [][]Yaml
    Nested map[string] *Yaml
}
```

But I actually hope there is a useful library to do this, as it seems like a relatively common task to do. Unfortunately,a search in Google didn't find anything. 
Does such a library exist? 
Thanks,

Comment: you mean use the yaml.Node class?

Comment: as i said, i don't want to decode / encode a yaml, i want to create one.

Comment: looking at the readme of the well known 3rd party https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml package, it seems good for unmarshelling yamls to structs, and marshelling structs to yamls, but not for dynamically building yamls.

Comment: Build a struct representing your data, then marshal it using the yaml package. If there is no fixed struct, build a map[string]interface{}, and marshal it.

Comment: thanks @BurakSerdar. a bit clunky, but this is the solution i was looking for. you can put in answer format so i can accept it.